# Fairly new in Haskell. Any help explaining what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated

Tags: function, haskell, tuples, fold, indices

This is my sumEvenOdd function that takes a list of numbers. It returns a tuple of two numbers: the sum of the even-index items in the given list, and the sum of the odd-index items. Indices are zero-based.

```
sumEvenOdd :: Num a => [a] -> (a, a)
sumEvenOdd (x:xs) = ((foldl1 (+) (evens(xs))), (foldl1 (+) (odds(xs)))) where
evens (x:xs) = x:odds xs
odds (_:xs) = evens xs
```

To get my odds I just skip a spot

If I call sumEvenOdd [1,2,3,4] should return (4,6)
or,
sumEvenOdd [] should return (0,0).

But I get " Exception:Non-exhaustive patterns in function odds "

I just don't see where the redundant pattern is.

Comment: your `evens` and `odds` do not take into account the empty list.

Comment: I strongly recommend you enable warnings with the `-Wall` flag and carefully read them. Many beginner's mistakes, such as this one, are caught by warnings. Here the warning would say something like "unhandled case: []" pointing at the empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no redundant pattern, there patterns are *non-exhaustive*: these do not consider the empty list. You thous implement `evens` and `odds` with:

```
sumEvenOdd :: Num a => [a] -> (a, a)
sumEvenOdd xs = (sum (evens xs), sum (odds xs))

evens :: [a] -> [a]
evens [] = []
evens (x:xs) = x : odds xs

odds :: [a] -> [a]
odds [] = []
odds (_:xs) = evens xs
```

You can use [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum). Using `foldl1 (+)` will not work for *empty* lists.

Comment: Would `(foldl (+) 0 evens xs, foldl (+) 0 odds xs) `   work as well? Thanks for the quick answer by the way

Comment: @User0name00 It would.  But `sum` would be generally preferable, since it is more expressive and can potentially be more efficient.